# Unable to create a tuple in a single statement by appending to list created by list comprehension

Tags: python, tuples, list-comprehension

Goal: Create a tuple consisting of the column headers of a pandas dataframe AND an additional column in a single, easy-to-understand statement.

For the example say:

```
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c']
fname = 'sample.txt'
```

I can create the tuple ('a', 'b', 'c', 'sample.txt') in three statements as follows:

```
y = [x for x in df.columns]
y.append(fname)
mytuple = tuple(y)
```

It's readable, but verbose. I can reduce this to two statements as:

```
y = [x for x in df.columns].append(fname)
mytuple = tuple(y)
```

This is not bad, but I still prefer to do it in one line.
My thought A is a single line statement should work like this:

```
mytuple = tuple([x for x in df.columns].append(fname))
```

Alas, that yields the error:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I also tried B (wild guess)

```
mytuple = tuple([[x for x in df.columns].append(fname)])
```

but that gives the wrong result

> (None,)

I would like to know 3 things:

1. Why does option A does not work as I think it should.
2. Is there a way to do this (non-obtusely) in a single statement.
3. If so, how is it done?

Comment: `list.append(value)` returns `None` and modifies the list in place, which is why A and B do not work as you expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.append()` mutates the list, but is returning `None`. This is the reason for your error. To write this in one line, use list concatenation instead of `list.append()`:

```
mytuple = tuple([x for x in df.columns] + [fname])
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to create a list first; just use the argument unpacking operator:

```py
mytuple = (*df.columns, fname)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mytuple = tuple(list(df.columns) + [fname])
```

Although, [@kaya3 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66281697/4046632) is probably the best one

Answer (score 2):

Because `.append()` doesn't reutn anything (it returtns None).

This is how its done:

```
print(tuple([x for x in df.colums] + [fname]))
```

or if `df.colums` is a list already:

```
print(tuple(df.colums + [fname]))
```

Comment: `print(tuple(df.colums + [fname]))` will not work. You will be surprised of the result. It will concatenate each column name and fname